# How can I concat cellvalues with new line in MS Excel?

Tags: excel, concatenation, newline

In excel I can introduce a new line inside a cell with a `[alt enter]`

```
Boo[alt enter]Far
```

results in:

```
Boo
Far
```

Now `A1` contains `Boo`, `A2` contains `Far`. How can I display these values in `A3` separated with a new line?

```
A3=A1[alt enter]&B1
```

results in BooFar

```
A3=A1&[alt enter]B1
```

results in BooFar

How can I get

```
Boo
Far
```

By using cell references?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

In **A3** enter:

```
=A1 & CHAR(10) & A2
```

and format **A3** for wrap text

Comment: Is it possible to embed the 'wrap text format' inside your formula?

Comment: No..........but you can pre-format the cell or a column of these cells before you enter the formula(s).

Answer (score 0):

If it helps anyone using Office on Mac, you should use `CHAR(13)` for line breaks.
For the above example, that would be

`=CONCATENATE(A1, CHAR(13), A2)`

And of course, format for wrap text.

The 10 and 13 represent Line Feed & Carriage Return characters.